# Xcode : let the user choose the background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background, uibutton

How do I have to do that the user can choose the background of the app by pressing a UIButton ?
By pressing the UIButton it wil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this as follows. When the user taps the button, presents a new view managed by a table view controller. The table should show on each row a thumbnail representing a possible background, and a text associated to the image, may be its name. When the user selects a row, you first save the choice (using the defaults, your own database or storing it in your core data model) and then change the background accordingly.

Comment: I'm a new to Cocoa dev , so could you please explaine with examples please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the time to post an example. However, if you are beginning programming on iOS devices you will find UITableView and UITableViewController commonly used classes. Take a look at their documentation to start with. Good luck.